# Turn off zend inArrayValidator in form .ini file

Tags: zend-framework

Hi I'm jsut wondering how you turn the default validator: inArrayValidator off in form ini files, I can turn it off in my controller like so:

```
$oForm->getElement("sitename")->setRegisterInArrayValidator(false);
```

I want to be able to do it in my .ini as to not clutter up my controller:

I have tried the following:

```
elements.0.type = "select"
elements.0.name = "sitename"
elements.0.options.label = "Site name"
elements.0.options.validators.inarrayvalidator = false
```

But this doesn't work, I get the following error:

```
Plugin by name '' was not found in the registry; used paths:\nZend_Validate_: Zend\/Validate\/
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ini file, you should reference `registerInArrayValidator` instead of `inArrayValidator` since the actual property in `Zend_Form` is called `registerInArrayValidator`.

The following config works:

```
[elements]

sitename.type = "select"
sitename.name = "sitename"
sitename.options.label = "Site name"
sitename.options.registerInArrayValidator = false
sitename.options.multiOptions[] = "Hello"
sitename.options.multiOptions[] = "There"
```